# k-th Smallest Element in the Union of Two Sorted Arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

[I could not understand the third algorithm here, which is the best O(lg m + lg n).](http://leetcode.com/2011/01/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-union-of.html) 
They say in the code if  Ai < Bj  => Ai < B(j-1). how is that ? ]

And given the problem  O(lg m + l g n) will be faster or O(k. log (min(m,n)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the invariant `i+j=k-1` puts us on a few possible situations. If we found the right **i** and **j** then it means that one of them is the **k-th** element. And it respects one of these conditions:

- if `Bj-1 < Ai < Bj`, then Ai must be the k-th smallest
- or else if
  `Ai-1 < Bj < Ai`, then Bj must be the k-th smallest.

If not, and we have that `A[i]<B[j]` but not `A[i]>B[j-1]` => the case that you asked *how is that possible*.
So `A[i] < B[j] => A[i] < B[j-1]` resulted as a consequence of not happening the first conditions.

**Second part of the question**:

> O(lg m + l g n) > O(k. log (min(m,n))

This is my opinion and I will tell you why. If one of **m** and **n** is a lot larger that the other (suppose n << m) we would have to compare: `log m + log n` with `k * log(n)`.

To have equality we would need `log m=(k-1)log n`. But since k is a constant and can be a small number and we supposed that n << m , this would result in `log m > k* log n`.

Still, the difference between the two complexities can prove to be small depending on **n** and **m**.